# Adding a splash screen to a windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I am making a windows forms application in C# using Visual Studio 2012.

I want to add a splash screen to it.

I googled about if but most of them I read are using a timer. But I do not want to show the startup/splash screen on an exact time period.

I only want to show it while loading the main applcation. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: AFAIK you can specify a splash screen in Application Properties.

Comment: Please show your efforts and do some search.

Comment: @wonko79 Thanks for the comment. I refereed to that before. It is using timers.

Comment: @kamilT Could you please explain it a little ?

Comment: @KamilT Not for Windows Forms applications.

Comment: @user3218743: The answer of Burimi uses a backgroundworker...

Comment: Tom Clements made a [pretty good splash screen](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C)... (5th link on google btw...)